# Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'... wont complete, Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, gradle

Flutter doctor -v gives

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.2.1, on Linux, locale en_US.UTF-8)
• Flutter version 2.2.1 at /home/salar/snap/flutter/common/flutter
• Framework revision 02c026b03c (4 weeks ago), 2021-05-27 12:24:44 -0700
• Engine revision 0fdb562ac8
• Dart version 2.13.1

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
    • Android SDK at /home/salar/Android/Sdk/
    • Platform android-30, build-tools 30.0.3
    • Java binary at: /home/salar/android-studio/jre/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.8+0-b944-P17168821)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at google-chrome

[✓] Android Studio (version 4.2)
    • Android Studio at /home/salar/android-studio
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.8+0-b944-P17168821)

[✓] Connected device (2 available)
    • LND L29 (mobile) • 9TKBB18625203190 • android-arm64  • Android 8.0.0 (API
      26)
    • Chrome (web)     • chrome           • web-javascript • Google Chrome
      91.0.4472.114

• No issues found!
```

But when i run the app LND L29 (mobile), gradle task assemble debug get stuck i leave it for approx five hours but it wont work, on ubuntu 20.04
I tried following things

```
flutter clean   //wont work

cd android 
./gradlew clean
./gradlew build   //also wont works

change physical device    //also wont works
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enter your android folder :

`cd android`

and run

`./gradlew cleanBuildCache`

And then try calling gradle directly with the --info flag in order to have more output to debug your issue if not solved.

`./gradlew  assembleDebug --info`